# MySQL Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 2

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have 3 nodejs express applications running in pm2 using different databases each and two of them keep getting the error "Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 2.". There are getting it both at the same time. I'm using pools with a connectionLimit of 50 in each of the application. This is how the configuration is made:

this.dbPool = mysql.createPool({
host: "localhost",
user: "apiuser",
password: "******************",
database: "******************",
debug: false,
connectionLimit: 50,
supportBigNumbers: true,
bigNumberStrings: true,
charset : 'utf8mb4'
})

The issue is not coming after a specific event or query. After a long time inactivity (8-10 hours) the apps do crash with this error.

It was suggested to increase the `max_connection` and the `max_allowed_packet`
values on mysql, which I did on the mysql.cnf file before restarting the mysql server. I already checked by querying `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ...` and
the values are shown as set in the mysql.cnf file:

```
max_connections=1024
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

I have also changed the group_concat_max_len `group_concat_max_len=50000`

However these changes haven't fixed the issue for now.

I am using the following mysql library version: `"mysql": "^2.18.1"`
MySQL Version is: `mysql  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

What could be the issue here? Is it a query that I'm doing or any configuration issue? Or version mismatch between mysql and the library maybe?
Unfortunately I'm not able to show you all the queries that I'm doing, since the API has around 80 endpoints and around 150 different queries.

Would love to hear any suggestion to solve this.

Stacktrace of the error:

```
Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 2
    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/home/apis/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:470:15)
    at Parser.write (/home/apis/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)
    at Protocol.write (/home/apis/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/apis/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/apis/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Have probably found out why exactly these two api's were crashing after (probably exact! 8 hours). Both apis have a class which runs some SQL queries at initial start using mysql.createConnection() instead of createPool(). These were all executed in a transaction. Well... It did miss the .end() or destroy() command after my commit() and this is where probably the wait_timeout of mysql came across and closed these unclosed connections after exact 28800 seconds (8 hours) and end up in crashing the api... Will came back if that did the trick and add it as answer.

Comment: good analysis, that sounds correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, that it was because of a not closed connection, like mentioned in my comment before.
So if you have this error, just check for not closed connections retrieved for an transaction... I've just overseen it, since this was a startup script that made initial queries ensuring required data is present for the api.